# How to relax subplot ratio in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I plot an array of images as subplots as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=32,ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
...
for n in range(32*3):
  ax = plt.subplot(32, 3, n)      # select where to plot
  plt.imshow(filt, cmap='gray')   # plot image
  n += 1
...
plt.show()
```

but the images are too small - seems like the `plt.show()` holds the horizontal/vertical ratio to 1, so the overall plot is square, but should be 32/3 ratio. As a result, my images look very small and distant within columns:
[image]
I tried using `tight_layout()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201514/matplotlib-subplots-are-too-narrow-with-tight-layout/51204293) and tried `plt.axes().set_aspect(32/3)` but it did not have any good effect. There are many examples that use equal number of subplots horizontally and vertically, so the subplots look normal, but in my case I have 32 rows and 3 columns which is scaled weirdly. What am I missing?

Comment: Tried using `plt.subplots_adjust (wspace=0.1)`?

Comment: @Ashish that did not help. Ideally, I would not want to specify this spacing. I expect the function to automatically size each subplot. As I mentioned earlier, if my subplot is of equal sides, for example (4x4), then subplots are evenly spaced with minimal distance of each other. But my case (32,3) does not work.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475508/how-to-combine-gridspec-with-plt-subplots-to-eliminate-space-between-rows-of-s) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376052/preventing-matplotlib-from-decrease-the-size-of-plotted-images-as-number-of-imag/49386898#49386898).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the second link seems to be the same problem as mine. Though, I can not figure out how to adapt the solution to my _forloop_. I included this line `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=32,ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)` before the _forloop_  (see updated code), but the final plot is the same.

Comment: The second link uses the same formulas as shown in the first. Both codes use for loops.

Comment: What is `filt.shape`?  Matplotlib tries very hard to draw square pixels... In other terms, adjust the `figsize` as suggested elsewhere.

Comment: @gboffi the pixels are drawn as squares. As you can see, each image is a made of 3x3 pixels and is square, so the pixels must be squares too.

Comment: If you do not change the `figsize`, as beautifully explained in the answers that  ImportanceOfBeingErnest  had kindly linked, because your `imshow`s are square and Matplotlib **forces** the aspect ratio of pixels to square, then the result cannot be different from what you've got.  REPEAT: change the `figsize`.

Comment: @gboffi thank you - adjusting `figsize` helped a little - my figure is now rectangular. However, the horizontal spacing between columns is still large and adjusting `wspace` and `hspace` as in the following `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=32, ncols=3, figsize=(3, 32))` and `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.01, hspace=0.1)` does not help. Any suggestions?